# OnClick Method could not function correctly with if else statement

Tags: android, onclick, textview

I've a if else statement in my code.

Supposingly, if I click on the Textview with the (lat("1.2960994") and lng("103.848237")), it will bring me to the next intent, which is map.class.

```
if(KEY_LATITUDE.equals("1.2960994") && KEY_LONGITUDE.equals("103.848237"))
```

However, when I click it(textview) , it didn't bring me to the next intent. In fact, it gave me the "else" code.

```
Toast.makeText(SingleMenuItemActivity.this, "Invalid MAP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I do not know what is wrong with my code, it just couldn't show the "IF" part.
Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance

This is part of my source code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

         //TODO Auto-generated method stub



    if(KEY_LATITUDE.equals("1.2960994") && KEY_LONGITUDE.equals("103.848237")){

    Intent intent = new Intent(SingleMenuItemActivity.this,map.class);
    intent.putExtra("MAP",KEY_LATITUDE.toString());
    intent.putExtra("MAP",KEY_LONGITUDE.toString());
    startActivity(intent);
        //startActivity(new Intent(SingleMenuItemActivity.this,
            //  map.class));

    /*Intent n = new Intent(MainActivity.this,map.class); 
    n.putExtra("lat",latitude.get(position).toString()); 
    n.putExtra("lng",longitude.get(position).toString());
    startActivity(n); */

    }
    else
    {
        //startActivity(new Intent(SingleMenuItemActivity.this,
            //map.class));


        Toast.makeText(SingleMenuItemActivity.this, "Invalid MAP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}



}
```

Comment: Did you check the values to see that BOTH of these are true, `KEY_LATITUDE.equals("1.2960994")` AND `KEY_LONGITUDE.equals("103.848237"`? Is `KEY_LATITUDE` and `KEY_LONGITUDE` `String`s?

Comment: what type is KEY_LATITUDE and KEY_LONGITUDE?

Comment: can you log the actual values of those keys and post them ?

Comment: @codeMagic both are true

Comment: @StefanBeike they are float, but I declare them as string

Comment: @njzk2 this are the actual values

Comment: I mean the values from the variables. What is the value in KEY_LATITUDE ?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell anything from here, but these are my recommendations:

1) Use proper Java naming conventions.  If `KEY_LATITUDE` and `KEY_LONGITUDE` are not constants then you should not make them all caps.  If they are constants, it seems rather pointless to compare them to something.

2) `KEY_LATITUDE` and `KEY_LONGITUDE` must not be those values.  You need to debug and find out what values they are instead.  To do this, try a Log statement like this:

`Log.d("coords", "lat: " + KEY_LATITUDE + " long: " + KEY_LONGITUDE);`

to see what the values actually are.  Use LogCat to search for the `coords` tag.  From that, you can see if you are getting the correct comparison you expect.

edit: I notice one other thing.  You are calling `toString()` on your `KEY_LATITUDE` and `KEY_LONGITUDE` values.  Are they not already Strings?  `.equals()` compares the equality of objects.  In your case you might need to try this instead:

```
if(KEY_LATITUDE.toString().equals("1.2960994") && KEY_LONGITUDE.toString().equals("103.848237"))
```

Comment: this is what it pass out 08-14 09:15:10.280: D/Plume_53500(23834): Got coordinates from network=(1.3800584,103.8452073) was:null

Comment: i mean, I've change the code, the number..forgot to mention that

Comment: @randomize Have you solved this yet?  Why are you converting the lat/long values to String objects instead of just comparing them in their primitive form?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
 if(KEY_LATITUDE.equals("1.2960994") && KEY_LONGITUDE.equals("103.848237"))
```

with

```
if(KEY_LATITUDE.toString().equals("1.2960994") && KEY_LONGITUDE.toString().equals("103.848237"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that KEY_LATITUDE and KEY_LONGITUDE aren't defined within your onClick method from what I can see. This can cause a problem because OnClickListener, if I'm not mistaken, is an anonymous inner class so any variable (other than class variables of your super class) cannot be used. Even if that isn't the case you should have code that directly gets the position of the view "v" that onClick hands you because that's the view that you clicked on and the only one you care about as far as I know. You can try storing the coords in a tag when the TextView is created (like `tv.setTag([latCoord, longCoord])`)and then accessing it within the onClick method by `v.getTag()`.